# How can I call a jquery function on selecting a dropdown option for dynamically created inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is what the page looks like currently:

[image]

The first one is hardcoded in and then the rest are added/removed by the buttons. The first one can also be added and removed from the buttons. I want to call a jquery function when the dropdown is changed to change the type from textbox/radiobutton (and text)/checkbox (and text) etc.

Currently it only works on the first Question/Answer and only works if it is the original and not dynamically created. I'm not sure why that is.

Here is how the Q/A's are created and removed

```
$("#addButton").click(function () {

    if (counter > max_fields) {
        alert("Only " + max_fields + " Questions allowed");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Question #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
          '" id="questionbox' + counter + '" value="" />' +
          ' <select id="choice'+ counter +'"><option>Type</option><option>Radio Button</option><option>Text Box</option><option>Check Box</option></select>' +
          '<button id = "remove' + counter + '">Remove</button>' +
          '<br/><label>Answer #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<div id="Answers' + counter + '">' +
          'Option 1: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
          '1" name="answerbox' + counter + '" value="" />' +
          '<br/>Option 2: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
          '2" name="answerbox' + counter + '" value="" />' +
          '<br/>Option 3: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
          '3" name="answerbox' + counter + '" value="" />' +
          '<br/>Option 4: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
          '4" name="answerbox' + counter + '" value="" /></div>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if (counter == 1) {
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
    }
    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
});
```

This is how I tried to get it to change types

```
$('#choice1').change(function () {
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("Answers1").children;
    alert(searchEles.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
        $('#answerbox1' + i).attr('type', selected_item);
        //alert(searchEles.length);
    }

});
```

The web page code is as follows

```
<input type='button' value='Add Question' id='addButton'/>
<input type='button' value='Remove Question' id='removeButton'/>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Question #1 : </label>
        <input type='text' id='questionbox1'/> 
        <select id="choice1" onchange="$('#choice').val('id');"> //this on change was added and currently does nothing it seems.
            <option value="">Type</option>
            <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
            <option value="text">Text Box</option>
            <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
        </select>
        <button id="remove1">Remove</button>
        <br/><label>Answer #1 : </label>
        <div id="Answers1">
            Option 1: <input type="text" id='answerbox11' name='answerbox1'  value="" />
            <br/>Option 2: <input type="text" id='answerbox12' name='answerbox1'  value="" />
            <br/>Option 3: <input type="text" id='answerbox13' name='answerbox1'  value="" />
            <br/>Option 4: <input type="text" id='answerbox14' name='answerbox1'  value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do something like onchange and then get the ID and go from there but that didn't work. I know it doesn't match the back end jquery name.

TL;DR

1. I don't know how to dynamically write the jQuery function to work
   for all of them.
2. I don't know why even if I hardcode it to `#choice1` it will work
   when its first created but not if i remove and add it even though it
   has the same exact values. I think it might MAYBE have to do with
   for loop, because the alert doesn't even trigger the second time
   around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
$(document).on("change", ".selector", function(){
  //do something

});
```

//Edit

Add to the select element class for example select-option and a tag that will hold the select's counter

```
//JS    
...'<select id="choice'+counter+'" class="select-option" number="'+counter+'">'...
```

and then your on change function would look something like

```
$(document).on("change", ".select-option", function(){
  //do something
  var selected_type = $(this).attr('value');
  var ans_number = $(this).attr('number');
  $("#answerbox"+ans_number).children('input').attr('type', selected_type);
});
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: This is the answer (Assuming you're using jQuery 1.7+), though you should use the closest parent of the .selector that is not added dynamically (such as the form or a containing div)

Comment: Is there a way I can abstract this out more to not have to use #choice1 but instead just send it the value? This is how I put it as well. $(document).on("change", "#choice1", function(){

Comment: Did you try to get the value of the selected option by $(this).attr("value") ?

Comment: how would I reference that though in this function? Sorry, I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do next with the selected value

Comment: $(document).on("change", ".selector", function(){
  //do something
});

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements use

```
$(selector).on("change", callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

If element is dynamic then Jquery will not bind directly as

```
$('#choice1').change(function (){});
```

But for that you need to call same function with some static element. 
For Ex:

```
 $(".listingDiv").find('#choice1').change(function (){});
```

or

```
$(document).find('#choice1').change(function (){});
```

and it will work. try it.

Answer (score 0):

When elements will be aded dynamically, best practice is to delegate the handler(s).  Put your handler on the containing div or window/document
.

Answer (score 0):

- First

  ```
  <select id="choice1" onchange="$('#choice').val('id');"> //this on change was added and currently does nothing it seems.
  ```

  This is one reason your never be called. If you bind an event listener to an element, you should not write the actual JS code inside the element.
- Second

  Bind your listener like this:

```js
$('#choice1').on("change", function () {
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("Answers1").children;
    alert(searchEles.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
        $('#answerbox1' + i).attr('type', selected_item);
        //alert(searchEles.length);
    }

});
```